# Layered elements with oncontextmenu bindings

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

Repro: https://jsfiddle.net/ssabc/cL6qxn1r/13/

I have a background element and a foreground element (you can think of it as a dialog popup on top of a canvas). When the user right-clicks on the foreground I would like to prevent the `context menu` from appearing in the background.

I tried binding a handler for the foreground's context menu and returning false from it to no avail:

```js
document.getElementById('above').oncontextmenu = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
}
```

As you can see in the JSFiddle, the `oncontextmenu`-event triggers on both elements. Here's a [screenshot showing event firing in the background no matter which element is right-clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aBufF.png)

Is there any way to prevent the background event from firing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add

```
e.stopPropagation();
```

to your child element right click event handler. With the change, it would look like this:

```
document.getElementById('above').oncontextmenu = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation(); // <=== add this
    getResultP().innerHTML += '<li>Dialog oncontextmenu called</li>';
  return false;
}
```

This prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree. Read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation).